# swift 4 json array struct

Tags: arrays, json, swift

How will the struct look when you have this data? Must you add the the Success, Code and message in the struct?

> "{"Entries":[{"Utility":"Electricity","ConsumptionDateTime":"2017-11-06","Consumption":0.6268,"Amount":0.94999999999999984},{"Utility":"Electricity","ConsumptionDateTime":"2017-11-07","Consumption":55.1076,"Amount":100.88000000000001},{"Utility":"Electricity","ConsumptionDateTime":"2017-11-08","Consumption":54.2914,"Amount":99.659999999999982},{"Utility":"Electricity","ConsumptionDateTime":"2017-11-09","Consumption":54.3062,"Amount":99.809999999999974},{"Utility":"Electricity","ConsumptionDateTime":"2017-11-10","Consumption":54.3584,"Amount":99.330000000000013},{"Utility":"Electricity","ConsumptionDateTime":"2017-11-11","Consumption":53.6868,"Amount":98.570000000000022},{"Utility":"Electricity","ConsumptionDateTime":"2017-11-12","Consumption":38.5152,"Amount":66.65}],"Success":true,"Code":0,"Message":""}"

```
struct consumptionResponse: Decodable {
    let Entries: String?
    let consumption: [consumptionEntrys]
    let Success: String?
    let Code: Int?
    let message: String?
}

struct consumptionEntrys: Decodable {

    // MARK: - Properties
    var consumptionUtility: String?
    var consumptionDateTime: String?
    let consumptionReading: Double?
    let consumptionAmount: Double?
 }
```

Comment: put in something like jsonprettyprint.com and go from there.

Comment: `let Entries: [consumptionEntrys]` is the correct thing for your first two variables inside `consumptionResponse`.

Answer (score 0):

As luk2302 said you could get the Pretty Print JSON and then form your structures from there.

An edited version of the Pretty Printed JSON yields the following:

```
{
"Entries": [
{
"Utility": "Electricity",
"ConsumptionDateTime": "2017-11-06",
"Consumption": 0.6268,
"Amount": 0.95
},
{
"Utility": "Electricity",
"ConsumptionDateTime": "2017-11-07",
"Consumption": 55.1076,
"Amount": 100.88
],
"Success": true,
"Code": 0,
"Message": ""
}
```

As such a viable model should be:

```
struct Response: Decodable{

let Entries: [Entries]?
let Success: Bool?
let Code: Int?
let Message: String?

}

struct Entries: Decodable{

let Utility: String?
let ConsumptionDateTime: String?
let Consumption: Double?
let Amount: Double?

}
```

You will of course need to check whether the variables are correct e.g. is the key: ConsumptionDateTime a String?

Anyway hopefully this will help you get started.